# How to make a specific editable cell as non editable in backgrid

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

I am using backgrid in my project ,I have a requirement like when i have selected a option in an dropdown of column i have to select a value in another dropdown and make the cell as non editable.

I am using backgrid:edited event to do this I am able to change the value but failing to make the cell as non editable.

Is there any way to make the cell as non editable in backgrid.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you started reading through Backgrid's source code?  This might help you figure it out

Comment: yes I have done the same ... and solved the issue

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer to your own question, this could be helpful to other and might result in increased reputation points for yourself.  Also it might have saved me a bit of effort as I started to tinker with your problem.  My rough idea would be to disable the other dropdown.  I will be interested to see if you post.

Comment: George plz check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found how to make an specific editable as non editable in back grid edited event

```
$("#gridid tr").each(function(index){
 //if some condition
 $("gridid    tr").find("td.mycolumnclsname).eq(index).unbind();
  });
```